# Check for user = root within linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, file-permissions, user-permissions

I am writing linux kernel code. I am in VFS and I want to modify it. I want to add a check to see whether or not the user is root and based on that make a decision. How do I do this? Is there a kernel version of getuid() ? Or does any structure like "current->" contain info on which user it is for the current process?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `current_cred()` as defined in `include/linux/cred.h`, which will give you a pointer to a `struct cred` itself defined in the same header. Something like

```
  if (current_cred()->uid != 0)
     return -EPERM;
```

Comment: This throws a type error. Maybe it didn't in '13, but now `current_cred()->uid` returns a `kuid_t` (not an integer).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `current_cred()->uid` now returns a `struct kuid_t`. To get the value you need `current_cred()->uid.val` & a final type cast to get rid of the warnings.

```
if ((int)current_cred()->uid.val != 0)
     return -EPERM;
```